# How to configure shared storage and replication feature of activemq subsystem in wildfly?

Tags: wildfly, activemq-artemis

I am working on wildfly 10, the messaging service on it is activemq, can anyone tell me exactly how you would configure the standalone-ha-full.xml of wildfly to use the shared storage and replication feature of activemq subsystem in wildfly ?

I found this usefull.. [blog]: http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-jms/jms-clustering-in-wildfly-and-jboss-eap

PS : I wanna run two VM's and demo the features using them.
Been lost from days, not able to find any material on this so please help

Comment: Please, no emoji except in comments. They add no detail to the question.

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [Ask] and [MCVE]. This seems like a server configuration problem that is not appropriate for SO.  Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's important to note something that's commonly missed; even though the [docs for Artemis](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/latest/index.html) are not Wildfly-centric, they document the same Artemis you have on Wildfly.

What I'd recommend you do is simple run the following examples. Once you get an idea about the tests, which are explained simplistically in the `main` class of the examples, then you can easily migrate over the configurations from the generated `broker.xml` files to your Wildfly configuration.

So, for this [shared store example](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/tree/master/examples/features/ha/stop-server-failover) and this [replication example](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/tree/master/examples/features/ha/replicated-transaction-failover) do the following:

1. `git clone <provided repo>`
2. `mvn verify`
3. Look at the `src/main/resources/activemq/server[0-2]`
4. Configure your Wildfly with the matching `messaging subsystem` configuration (you'll see they're almost **exactly** the same!)
5. Add the `<noserver>true<noserver>` and remove the `<ignore>${noserver}</ignore>` declaration from the pom.xml and run the main method of the example pointing to your Wildfly server/port to make sure you've gotten your configuration right
6. Then you have a demo using Artemis with Wildfly demonstrating the same capabilities

Have fun and enjoy.